# factorial trailing zeroes BigO problems

Tags: algorithm, big-o, factorial, trailing

when I submit to leetcode, it run case 500/502 but failed, reason: 1808548329. But when I run it on my own mac, it gave the same answer as the accepted one.

my code :

```
int trailingZeroes(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    int tmp = 0; //check every number in [1, i]
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        tmp = i;
        while (tmp % 5 == 0) {
            count++;
            tmp /= 5;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

and the ac answer:

```
int trailingZeroes2(int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 0 : n / 5 + trailingZeroes(n / 5);
}
```

they run the same result, on my mac:

```
std::cout << trailingZeroes(1808548329) << std::endl; //452137076
std::cout << trailingZeroes2(1808548329) << std::endl; //452137076
```

Is the reason that first solution not accepted because of `time complexity?`
(cus' i am running it on my own mac, but it gives the same answer that the ac gave)

how can i calculate the time complexity of the first solution,

is it `O(NlogN)` ? I am not sure. can u do me a favor？ : -)

---

edited, remove pics.

Comment: Replace images with text. Makes it easier for everybody.

Comment: sorry, i am greenhand here, it said, to post images need at least 10 reputations.. i will try it later, thanks any way.

Comment: Do not post images. Instead, use text. Copy your code from your editor into your question.

Comment: got it, it looks better, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is `O(n)`.

- The inner loop repeats at least once every 5 items
- The inner loop repeats at least twice every 25 items
- ...
- The inner loop repeats at least k times every 5^k items.

Summing it together gives you that the inner loop runs:

```
n/5 + n/25 + n/125 + ... + 1 = 
n (1/5 + 1/25 + 1/125 + ... + 1/n)
```

This is [sum of geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum), which is in `O(n)`

In addition, the outer loop itself has O(n) iterations, with each constant cost, if ignoring the inner loops, so this remains `O(n)`.

---

The alternative solution, however runs in `O(logn)`, which is significantly more efficient.

Comment: Thumbs up to u. Thanks. : )